# Выпадающее меню в Python (pygame)

Tags: python, pygame

как создать в питоне выпадающее меню с помощью графического модуля pygame? (задача, есть множество цветов и нужно выбрать один из списка)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте адаптировать под свои нужды вот эту библиотеку:

http://simple-pygame-menu.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

**Пример кода:**

```
menu_data = (
    'Main',
    'Item 0',
    'Item 1',
    (
        'Things',
        'Item 0',
        'Item 1',
        'Item 2',
        (
            'More Things',
            'Item 0',
            'Item 1',
        ),
    ),
    'Quit',
)
PopupMenu(menu_data)
for e in pygame.event.get():
    if e.type == USEREVENT and e.code == 'MENU':
        print 'menu event: %s.%d: %s' % (e.name,e.item_id,e.text)
        if (e.name,e.text) == ('Main','Quit'):
            quit()
```